# Angular 5 - Can't get lazy loading with string syntax to work

Tags: module, lazy-loading, angular5

I'm trying to lazy load my modules via routing and I can't get it to work. This si what I have:

app.routing.module:

```
   const routes: Routes = [
  // basic routes
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'schedule', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'schedule',
    loadChildren: './modules/schedule/schedule.module#ScheduleModule',
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LogoutGuard] },
  {
    path: 'reports',
    loadChildren: './modules/reports/reports.module#ReportsModule',
    canActivate: [LoginGuard]
 }
];

 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
```

Example of a lazy loaded module:

schedule.module:

```
 @NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ScheduleRoutingModule,
```

schedule-routing.module:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   component: ScheduleComponent
 }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

When I run this and I attempt to navigate to the /schedule path I get this error:

```
   core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:20), <anonymous>:27:34)
at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6558)
at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6542)
at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
```

I was able to get it working when I did it like this:

app.routing.module:

```
  export function loadSchedule() {
   return ScheduleModule;
  }

  const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'schedule',
   loadChildren: loadSchedule,
```

But that doesn't work with AOT compiling.

What am I missing here? Seems like I'm doing everything right.

Edit - My Versions:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.2",


     "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
```

Comment: I hit same issue. Nothing works so I tried `npm update` on my project. Then run it again and it works like a charm

Comment: same here, run `ng build` and then `serve` your app again!